# Read() function

Tags: io, go

http://play.golang.org/p/Opb7pRFyMf

```
    // func (f *File) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error)
    record, err := reader.Read()
```

Is the Read() function defined in os package?
I am trying to understand this code but cannot find where the Read() function is defined... if that is the one in os package, it returns integer for record variable. But how come it is able to print out the text in the text file?

Answer (score 0):

`Reader` is the interface that wraps the basic `Read` method.

```
type Reader interface {
    Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

`Read` method takes a slice of byte as an argument and returns `(number of bytes read, error)`

```
myReader := strings.NewReader("This is my reader")
arr := make([]byte, 4)
for {
// n is number of bytes read
    n, err := myReader.Read(arr)
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    }
    fmt.Println(string(arr[:n]))
}
```

Output:

```
This
 is 
my r
eade
r
```

`string(arr[:n])` converts content of slice `arr` to string.

To read more about `Read` and `io.Reader`, refer this [article](https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/streaming-io-in-go-d93507931185)